# Error: 'Inventory ID' cannot be found in the system

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am working on a form in Acumatica, I am trying to select InventoryID from Purchase Order, specifically from POLine. Here is my code

```
[PXDBInt()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory ID")]
[PXDefault()]
[PXParent(typeof(Select<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<POInspectionDetail.inventoryID>>>>))]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<POLine.inventoryID,
      LeftJoin<POInspectionDetail, On<POLine.inventoryID, Equal<POInspectionDetail.inventoryID>>>,
        Where<POLine.orderNbr, Equal<Current<POInspection.orderNbr>>,
        And<POLineExt.qControl, Equal<True>>>>),
            typeof(POLine.siteID),
            typeof(POLine.orderQty),
            typeof(POLineExt.qControl))]
public int? InventoryID { get; set; }

public class inventoryID : IBqlField{}
```

I can see the ID like in this image [Selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ismIe.png), but if I select it, it shows me the error.

Can you help me solve this? Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

```
protected void POInspectionDetail_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
  POInspectionDetail poInspectiondetail = e.Row as POInspectionDetail;



  if(poInspectiondetail.InventoryID != null)
    {
      POLine polines = (POLine)PXSelectorAttribute.Select<POInspectionDetail.inventoryID>(cache, poInspectiondetail);

      poInspectiondetail.WarehouseID = polines.SiteID;
      poInspectiondetail.OpenQty = polines.OrderQty;
      poInspectiondetail.QtyonReceipts = polines.ReceivedQty;
    }      
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlYXm.png)

Comment: which line in the posted code is line 30 (as the error points out)? Also, you should be setting the fields in RowSelecting - not row selected. Row Selecting would be for unbound fields. Row Selected is for UI logic such as visible or enabled.

Comment: this line, POLine polines = (POLine)PXSelectorAttribute.Select<POInspectionDetail.inventoryID>(cache, poInspectiondetail);
I tried using Row Selecting and it did nothing unfortunately

Comment: you should call cache.setvalueext<> in rowselecting rather than set the row values as you have in your example. Does the POInspectionDetail dac inherit from another DAC? Could be a conflict with your PXParent which points to InventoryItem. Try to remove that attribute and try again.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the cache, and it works. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inventory ID displayed to the user is the CD value - not the int ID value.

The issue you might be having is selecting or using the ID vs CD value?

In your example I would search on InventoryItem and join the 2 tables you have.

Then in your selector add `SubstituteKey = typeof(InventoryItem.InventoryCD), DescriptionField = typeof(InventoryItem.descr)`

Comment: I tried using that, but I got this error because I want to add an event that include this field. The event and error is updated in the question